# Navigate to an external website on button Click

Tags: reactjs

In my app users click on button and navigate to external website. This external website is picked dynamically based on a form they fill.

Here, on clicking the button  is not working.

What I am doing wrong here?

```
 const handleLink1 =()=>{
        <Link
        to={{
            pathname: `${data.url}`
        }}
        target="_blank"
    >
        {' '}
 
    </Link>
        
    }
```

```
<button onClick={handleLink1} className="btn-primary"> {data.buttonName}</button>``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleLink1` should be like this.

```
const handleLink1 = () => {

    window.open(data.url);

}
```

```
<button onClick={handleLink1} className="btn-primary"> {data.buttonName}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the code for `handleLink1`?

Anyways, if `handleLink1` is anything like `handleLink2`, your mistake is creating a `Link` component in the event handler. It'll never be rendered. What you have to do instead, is wrap your `button` component in the `Link` component, like so:

```js
<Link
  to="somewhere"
>
  <button className="some-class">Click me to go somewhere!</button> //No need for the onClick event handler.
</Link>
```

*Edit*

Maybe the below will help clarify:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const IllNeverRender = () => {
  return <p>Nope</p>;
};

const IllRender = () => {
  return <p>Yep</p>;
};

export default function LinkButton() {
  const [Component, setComponent] = useState();

  const renderOnClickWrong = (event) => {
    <IllNeverRender />; // This component isn't returned from the handler, nor would it render if it was returned.
  };

  const renderOnClickRight = (event) => {
    setComponent(<IllRender />);
  };

  return (
    // Only components returned from a functional component, or a React Component's render method, gets rendered.
    <div>
      <Link to={{ pathname: "/somewhere" }}>
        <button>Go somewhere!</button>
      </Link>
      <button onClick={renderOnClickWrong}>Go nowhere.</button>
      <button onClick={renderOnClickRight}>Render something.</button>
      {Component}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your code, but I don't think returning `<Link>` from click handler function is the correct solution.  `<Link>` from react-router will only provide you ways to navigate around routes of your app.
To navigate to external url, you can either make use of `<a>` tag or `window.location.href` or `window.open()` .I believe you meant to do

```
const handleLink1 = () => {
   window.open(data.url, '_blank');     
}

<button onClick={handleLink1} className="btn-primary"> {data.buttonName}</button>
```

or instead of button directly use

```
   <a
      class='btn-primary'
      href=`${data.url}`
      target='_blank'
      rel="noopener"
      aria-label='Github'
    >
      {data.buttonName}
    </a>
```

correct me if I'm mistaken :)

Answer (score -1):

let home = "https://explorer.solana.com/tx/" + url;

window.open(home);

This is the perfect source code.